# Python __iadd__ TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=

Tags: python, algorithm, object, simulation, operation

I am building a battle simulation program. Running into TypeError. Unable to resolve. Any help would be appreciated. I can't seem to get the iadd function working. I'm trying to add new Pokemon objects to the existing PokemonTrainer object by using the iadd function in python. Anyone has any ideas on how to execute this?

main.py

```
name = input("State your name: ")
player = PokemonTrainer(name)

player += Pokemon("Staryu", ElementType.WATER, [
    Move("water blast", ElementType.WATER, 5),
    Move("water cyclone", ElementType.WATER, 6)
    ])
```

pokemon_trainer.py

For the **iadd**, I'm using type-based dispatch to deal with the parameter. If it is of type Pokemon, call the add_pokemon method on self and then return the self object. If it is of type Item, call the add_item method on self and then return the self object. Otherwise, raise a TypeError.

```
from pokemon import Pokemon

class PokemonTrainer:

    def __init__(self, name, pokemon = [], items = [], current_active_pokemon = None):
        self.name = name
        self.pokemon = pokemon
        self.items = items
        self.current_active_pokemon = current_active_pokemon


    def __iadd__(self, other):

        self.pokemon.append(other)

        if (type(other) == type(Pokemon)):
            self.add_pokemon(other)

        elif (type(other) == type(Item)):
            self.add_item(other)

        else:
            raise TypeError("Only Pokemon or Item type are allowed")

        return self

    def add_pokemon(self, pkmn):

        self.pokemon.append(pkmn)

        if (self.current_active_pokemon == None):
            self.current_active_pokemon = pkmn


    def add_item(self, item):

        self.items.append(item)
```

pokemon.py

```
class Pokemon:

    def __init__(self, name, pokemon_type, moves):
        self.name = name
        self.pokemon_type = pokemon_type
        self.moves = moves

        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.max_hp = 100
        self.current_hp = self.max_hp
        self.attack_power = 1
        self.defense_power = 1
        self.fainted = False
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact issue here is, but just a side note, *never* use a mutable object like a list as a default argument like you are with `...pokemon = [], items = [],...`. That will cause subtle problems. It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: The design is also questionable: `list.__iadd__` adds the elements of another list to the first list, not arbitrary objects: it's `some_list += [3]`, not `some_list += 3`.

Comment: `test` is suppose to be `player`. I had a typo

Comment: i updated the question and the code

Comment: read your stacktrace and see on exactly _which_ line the TypeError is occurring.

Comment: `pokemon_trainer.py", line 29, in __iadd__: raise TypeError("Only Pokemon or Item type are allowed")` I have type check in the iadd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want `isinstance(other, Pokemon)` instead of `type(other) == type(Pokemon)`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Also relevant here: [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)